# prediction algorithm using rnn

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

Goal : prediction of ethanol concentration regarding biological conditions over time.

I kept only the 5 conditions most correlated to ethanol concentration and kept only 8 hours values.
my train data have 3 experiments R1,R2 and R3 and 5 samples A,B,C,D,E.
My test data have 2 experiments, T1 and T2 and 3 samples, A,B,C.

For each sample of each experiment we have value of ethanol concentration as well as conditions value.

I want to predict ethanol concentration over time (hour1,hour2...hour8) using Rnn.

My algorithm works but before the prediction, when I wanted to evaluate the model on the test data, the R2 is very very low even negative. I don't know why.

I think there is a problem with the Time sequence.
I don't know how to fix it.

here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras import backend as K
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

# Fonction de perte personnalisée
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))

# Charger les données train et test 
df_train = pd.read_csv('/content/trainset8.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('/content/testset8.csv')

# Sélectionner les 5 conditions biologiques les plus corrélées avec la concentration d'éthanol
X = df_train.iloc[:,4:37] # les variables indépendantes
y = df_test.iloc[:,3] # variabke dépendante
correlations = X.corrwith(y)
correlations = correlations.abs().sort_values(ascending=False)
top_5_conditions = correlations.head(5).index.tolist()

top_5_conditions

# Sélectionner les colonnes correspondantes
cols_to_keep = ["Time", "Sample", "Experiment", "Ethanol_Concentration"] + top_5_conditions
train_data  = df_train[cols_to_keep]
test_data = df_test[cols_to_keep]

train_data

# Créer des séquences de longueur 8 pour train et test
def create_sequences(data):
    sequences = []
    for sample, exp in data.groupby(['Sample', 'Experiment']):
        for i in range(0, len(exp)-7):
            seq = exp.iloc[i:i+8][['C115', 'C120', 'C123', 'C104', 'C119']].values
            sequences.append(seq)
    return np.array(sequences)

train_sequences = create_sequences(train_data)
test_sequences = create_sequences(test_data)

# Normaliser les données pour accélérer l'apprentissage
mean, std = train_sequences.mean(), train_sequences.std()
train_sequences = (train_sequences - mean) / std
test_sequences = (test_sequences - mean) / std

# Diviser les données train en ensembles d'entrainement et de validation
train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(train_sequences, train_data.groupby(['Sample', 'Experiment'])['Ethanol_Concentration'].apply(list).values, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Créer le modèle LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=64, input_shape=(8, 5)))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(loss=root_mean_squared_error, optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001))

train_y = np.array([np.array(i) for i in train_y])
val_y = np.array([np.array(i) for i in val_y])

# Entrainer le modèle
model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_data=(val_X, val_y))

# Evaluer le modèle sur les données de test
test_X = test_sequences.reshape((-1, 8, 5))
test_y = test_data.groupby(['Sample', 'Experiment'])['Ethanol_Concentration'].apply(list).values
predictions = model.predict(test_X)

# Afficher les prédictions
for i, (sample, exp) in enumerate(test_data.groupby(['Sample', 'Experiment'])):
    print('Sample:', sample, 'Experiment:', exp['Experiment'].unique()[0])
    print('Actual:', test_y[i])
    print('Predicted:', predictions[i])

test_y = np.array([np.array(i) for i in test_y])
test_y_single = [np.mean(y) for y in test_y]
test_y_single = np.array(test_y_single)

test_X = test_sequences.reshape((-1, 8, 5))
test_y = test_data.groupby(['Sample', 'Experiment'])['Ethanol_Concentration'].apply(list).values
predictions = model.predict(test_X)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# Calculer le coefficient de corrélation (R2)
r2 = r2_score(test_y_single, predictions)

# Afficher le coefficient de corrélation (R2)
print('Coefficient de corrélation (R2) :', r2)[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cppj.png)
```

- Prediction over time (h1,h2,h3...)
- R2 good enough
- Using rnn model